# Reddit Script - Admin Account in example.ini

Tags: python, reddit

I have installed and setup reddit. It is working. I'm unable to add admin account. How can I add admin account?

Documentation states:

```
Create an account and add it to the admins line in example.ini
```

But I unable to find admins line.

My second question is, With which URL I access admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [the `employees` section](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/example.ini#L746-L747):

```
# permissions! each user should have one of admin, sponsor, or employee as their permission level
employees = reddit:admin
```

An account with administrator privileges will have a "turn admin on" link in the top-right; after enabling that, you'll get an additional menu with links to various tools.